# How can i make this method async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I was wondering how i could make this method async, it gives me an error:   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Here's my code:

```
void OnRegister(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
}
```

Comment: SCNR: Have you considered "*marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're welcome:

`async void OnRegister(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
    }`

You can't use await without a async method(this would not make any sense).

Comment: Thanks, you're right when i think about it it makes absolutely no sense... Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
async Task<int> OnRegisterAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate the method which contains 'await' with 'async'.
In your case I'm guessing you can't make OnRegister return a Task so you'll need a helper method. Something like this should work:

```
void OnRegister(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsync();
}

async void RegisterAsync() {
    await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();  
}
```

Notice how the RegisterAsync method is decorated with 'async' and returns a Task. Which in turn needs to be started by the caller.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: It gives an error that you cant call a start on a promise?